# VectorAngle[] relative to specific origin?

Tags: geometry, vector

`VectorAngle[]` computes the angle between two vectors from the origin (I assume `{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}`).

Can we use a reference point different than the origin? Didn't see this option in the docs.

For instance, what's the angle between `Pt1` and `Pt2` below, with `referencePoint` as the origin?

```
referencePoint = {2.0, 1.0, -0.5};
Pt1 = {3.0, 2.1, 1.9};
Pt2 = {0.7, 0.8, 0.9};
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[referencePoint],
  Blue, Point[Pt1], Green, Point[Pt2],
  Black, Arrow[{referencePoint, Pt1}], Arrow[{referencePoint, Pt2}]},
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}]
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I don't think I understand how to calculate the angle between two vectors *from another point*. Do you need [`SolidAngle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolidAngle.html) instead?

Comment: @MarcoB that seems promising, I think what I'm asking *might* be a special case of the SolidAngle[] operation, for what I can see there you add as many vectors as needed to compare against the reference, so I guess 2 vectors is the "base" case. Never heard of this function, I'll explore it more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

```
PolygonAngle[Polygon[{referencePoint, Pt1, Pt2}], 1]
VectorAngle[Pt1 - referencePoint, Pt2 - referencePoint]
```

> ```
> 1.2246306333350612`
> ```

> ```
> 1.2246306333350612`
> ```